# Можно ли в Qt делать необычные окна?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Надо написать программу на Qt/C++ (ОС Arch Linux), которая по сути является оконным менеджером.

Но только окна там должны перемещаться по "кубу" (только вид, соответственно изнутри куба и там не куб, а комната.

Вопрос в следующем:

- Как такое возможно реализовать?
- С помощью каких библиотек? (я так понял, что средств QT для этого недостаточно)

Я смог сделать что-то похожее, но только при помещении под-окон программы в какую-то область на них просто накладывается маска, делающая эти окна трапециевидной формы, но содержимое этих окон надо делать в перспективе (как на фото снизу)

Буду рад любой помощи от название библиотек до чьих-нибудь github-ов с похожей реализацией

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотри вот этот пример: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-demos-embeddeddialogs-example.html